# InstantiationException in hadoop map reduce program

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, jdom

I am new to Hadoop framework. I was trying to write a program which reads XML file from hdfs, parses it using JDOM and sends it to a database. The following is the Java file

```
package JDOMprs;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;

import com.vertica.hadoop.VerticaOutputFormat;
import com.vertica.hadoop.VerticaRecord;

public class ExampleParser extends Configured implements Tool {
    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {
        private final static DoubleWritable one = new DoubleWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();
        private List mylist;

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            context.write(value, one);
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text, VerticaRecord> {
        VerticaRecord record = null;
        String src_name;
        String comment;
        String rev_by;
        String rev_dt;
        String com_title;

        public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            super.setup(context);
            try {
                record = new VerticaRecord(context.getConfiguration());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IOException(e);
            }
        }

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values,
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            if (record == null) {
                throw new IOException("No output record found");
            }

            /******************** JDOM PARSER ***************************/
            SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
            // File xmlFile = new
            // File("C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/VerticaHadoop/src/JDOMprs/HadoopXML.xml");

            try {
                Document document = (Document) builder.build(key.toString());
                Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
                List list = rootNode.getChildren("source");
                // List ls= new ArrayList();
                // Jdomparse jp= new Jdomparse();
                // ls=jp.getParse(key);
                //
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                    Element node = (Element) list.get(i);

                    // System.out.println("Source Name : " +
                    // node.getChildText("source-name"));
                    // System.out.println("comment : " +
                    // node.getChildText("comment"));
                    // System.out.println("review by : " +
                    // node.getChildText("review-by"));
                    // System.out.println("review date : " +
                    // node.getChildText("review-date"));
                    // System.out.println("comment-title : " +
                    // node.getChildText("comment-title"));

                    record.set(0, node.getChildText("source-name").toString());
                    record.set(0, node.getChildText("comment").toString());
                    record.set(0, node.getChildText("review-by").toString());
                    record.set(0, node.getChildText("review-date").toString());
                    record.set(0, node.getChildText("comment-title").toString());
                }

            } catch (IOException io) {
                System.out.println(io.getMessage());
            } catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
                System.out.println(jdomex.getMessage());
            }
            /****************** END OF PARSER *****************************/

            context.write(new Text("reviewtbl"), record);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Set up the configuration and job objects
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        conf = job.getConfiguration();
        conf.set("mapreduce.job.tracker", "local");
        job.setJobName("vertica test");

        job.setInputFormatClass(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/user/cloudera/input"));

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(VerticaRecord.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(VerticaOutputFormat.class);
        job.setJarByClass(ExampleParser.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        VerticaOutputFormat.setOutput(job, "reviewtbl", true, "source varchar",
                "comment varchar", "rev_by varchar", "rev_dt varchar",
                "com_title varchar");
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new ExampleParser(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }
}
```

but I am getting the following exceptions.

```
12/12/20 02:41:34 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://0.0.0.0/var/lib/hadoop-0.20/cache/mapred/mapred/staging/root/.staging/job_201212191356_0006
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:947)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:967)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$500(JobClient.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:880)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:833)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:833)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:476)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:506)
        at ExampleParser.run(ExampleParser.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at ExampleParser.main(ExampleParser.java:153)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
        at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:113)
        ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
job.setInputFormatClass(
      org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.class);
```

You can't use / instantiate the `FileInputFormat` class: it's an abstract class.

If you want to parse the XML yourself then you'll need to write your own `InputFormat` that extends `FileInputFormat`, and the record reader can pass the entire contents to the mapper as the value. I think the *Hadoop - The Definitive Guide* has an example for `WholeFileInputFormat`, or something like that, or Google will probably have something:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=wholefileinputformat

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris White....i changed FileInputFormat to TextInputFormat and it worked....

Comment: @AshishBanerjee Thousand thanks for your comment sharing your knowledge. It saved me many hours I guess. I was still using .txt files as inputs and I was using 2 mappers with one reducer. And for that I used MulitipleInputs.AddInputPath method and FileInputFormat argument for that gave me the above error. But your simple tric made me succeed. Cheers..!