# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException running mapreduce code on eclipse using cygwin

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, hadoop, cygwin

Hi I am running mapreduce code on eclipse using Cygwin. I am able to successfully run wordcount program in this environment. But for my new code I am getting below exception.
My program does not have any reducer job/class. I also debug the code in eclipse. All mapper jobs running successfully and writing output in context. After that exception is thrown. Temporary output folders are created but no final output.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:215)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:113
    ... 3 more
```

Please find my main function below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length < 5) {
        System.out.println("Arguments: [model] [dictionnary] [document frequency] [tweet file] [output directory]");
        return;
    }
    String modelPath = args[0];
    String dictionaryPath = args[1];
    String documentFrequencyPath = args[2];
    String tweetsPath = args[3];
    String outputPath = args[4];
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.setStrings(Classifier.MODEL_PATH_CONF, modelPath);
    conf.setStrings(Classifier.DICTIONARY_PATH_CONF, dictionaryPath);
    conf.setStrings(Classifier.DOCUMENT_FREQUENCY_PATH_CONF, documentFrequencyPath);
    // do not create a new jvm for each task
    conf.setLong("mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks", -1);
    Job job = new Job(conf, "classifier");
    job.setJarByClass(MapReduceClassifier.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setMapperClass(ClassifierMap.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(tweetsPath));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to your issue:
[InstantiationException in hadoop map reduce program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992063/instantiationexception-in-hadoop-map-reduce-program)

You may want to check that none of the classes you provided to the JOB are abstract.